# CURL Command to NodeJS - PUT Request OctetStream

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, networking

I need to make this curl command into a nodejs request, either using `fetch`, `request` or `axios` networking libraries

The request needs to `PUT` the file data to the `URL`

```sh
curl -v -H "Content-Type:application/octet-stream" --upload-file C:/Users/deanv/Pictures/test3.mp4 "https://www.example.com/file/upload"
```

I've tried using [CurlConverter](https://curlconverter.com/#node-request) to convert my curl command to node code, but this doesn't work as I cant add the file data.

```js
var fetch = require('node-fetch');

fetch('https://www.example.com/file/upload', {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
    }
});
```

All help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
// setup modules
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const FormData = require('form-data');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// setup paths
const pathToFile = 'C:/Users/deanv/Pictures/test3.mp4';
const uploadUrl = 'https://www.example.com/file/upload';

// create form, 'content-type' header will be multipart/form-data
const form = new FormData();

// read the file as stream
const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(pathToFile));

// add the file to the form
form.append('my_file', fileStream);

fetch(uploadUrl, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: form
    }).then((res) => {
        console.log('done: ', res.status);
        return res.text();
    })
    .then((res) => {
        console.log('raw response: ', res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('err', err);
    });
```

Comment: I get a `done 400` as the status code logged to the console

Comment: That's short for "400 Bad Request". The server complains about something.. I've updated the code to log the server response

Comment: I just used curl and use exec to call it. thanks for helping. i just gave up on using node js when curl did it perfectly